# How to check if a user has a permission or a role using an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I wanna make a command `foo` which says `bar` when executed. I want the user to have either the `fooBar` role or the `administrator` permission in the guild using an if statement. I have tried this:

```
class FooBar:
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
    async def foo(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("bar")
```

But, thats only for the permission, how would I check for a role too. I tried using an error handler but I again need to see if the user has the role using an if statement. What I tried was:

```
class FooBar:
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
    async def foo(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("bar")
    @foo.error()
    async def fooErr(self,error,ctx):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermission) and (code to check if the user has a role):
            print("bar")
```

But, I get stuck at the point of checking if the user has a role again. Anything I can do for this or is it just not possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply add a `commands.has_role` decorator? You can have multiple checks, not only one

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński oh, I didnt know you could have multiple checks. Thanks.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński What if I had a bunch of roles all in a list, what would I do then? For example, ['foo','bar','fooBar']

Comment: You can use the `commands.has_any_role` decorator and unpack the list when passing it

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Late response, but what if I have it in a database and want to access it by doing `SELECT roles FROM servers WHERE id={ctx.guild.id}`?

Comment: I'm unsure what library or even database you're using, but if you get a list of role ID's/names it will still work the same

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I am using SQLite3. The thing is, I can not pass it in the decorator as I am getting it inside of the function ._.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem, thanks to Lukasz this answer worked:

```py
class FooBar:
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
    @commands.has_role("fooBar")
    async def foo(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("bar")
```